# grafana container exiting after container is created

Tags: docker, grafana

I want to access grafana web ui at localhost:3000. I wrote a dockerfile for it.
I used the steps from here- [grafana-installation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/debian/).

This is my dockerfile

```
# Use the official Ubuntu image as the base image
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https software-properties-common wget \
    && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings/ \
    && wget -q -O - https://apt.grafana.com/gpg.key | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/grafana.gpg > /dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/grafana.gpg] https://apt.grafana.com stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/grafana.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y grafana

CMD ./bin/grafana-server

EXPOSE 3000
```

When I run the container command the container is exiting.How to get grafana web ui?

```
 docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --rm --name mygrafana 2d8021be6d37
```

Here are the logs in docker desktop hub

```
2024-01-30 19:52:59 Grafana server is running with elevated privileges. This is not recommended
2024-01-30 19:52:59 Grafana-server Init Failed: Could not find config defaults, make sure homepath command line parameter is set or working directory is homepath
```

EDIT:
rebuilding and using CMD["grafana-server"] didnt't help.Something is wrong with the path

Edit: grafana-server is present in /usr/sbin/grafana-server
This is grafana-server file

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Wrapper for the grafana binary
# This file serves as a wrapper for the grafana binary. It ensures we set
# the system-wide Grafana configuration that was bundled with the package as we
# use the binary.

GRAFANA_HOME="${GRAFANA_HOME:-/usr/share/grafana}"

EXECUTABLE="$GRAFANA_HOME/bin/grafana"

if [ ! -x $EXECUTABLE ]; then
 echo "$EXECUTABLE not installed or not executable"
 exit 5
fi

CMD=server

eval $EXECUTABLE "$CMD" "$@"
```

Comment: Start by looking at the logs: `docker logs mygrafana`

Comment: @user23320998   You are using CMD ./bin/grafana-server, but this path might not be correct depending on where Grafana is installed in the Docker container. Can you confirm this. 
 You can try using **CMD ["grafana-server"]**
This change uses the default command format and assumes grafana-server is in your PATH. After making this change, rebuild your Docker image and run the container again.

Comment: You do not need to install the grafana by your own. Why do not you just use official grafana docker image and run it with ```docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=grafana grafana/grafana-enterprise```. For more info see https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/docker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use official [Grafana Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/grafana) instead of creating own, but for education purpose below you have what I've done to make it works

---

I have changed your `CMD ./bin/grafana-server` in `Dockerfile` to

```
USER grafana
WORKDIR /usr/share/grafana
CMD [ "/usr/sbin/grafana-server", "--config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini", "cfg:default.paths.data=/var/lib/grafana" ]
```

I added minimal arguments to make, but if you want more check below

From file `/etc/init.d/grafana-server` in image we can get how it's starting as service (so not for Docker), we can see options line:

```bash
DAEMON_OPTS="server --pidfile=${PID_FILE} --config=${CONF_FILE} --packaging=deb cfg:default.paths.provisioning=$PROVISIONING_CFG_DIR cfg:default.paths.data=${DATA_DIR} cfg:default.paths.logs=${LOG_DIR} cfg:default.paths.plugins=${PLUGINS_DIR}"
```

And environment variables

```bash
NAME=grafana-server
DESC="Grafana Server"
DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME

GRAFANA_USER=grafana
GRAFANA_GROUP=grafana
GRAFANA_HOME=/usr/share/grafana
CONF_DIR=/etc/grafana
WORK_DIR=$GRAFANA_HOME
DATA_DIR=/var/lib/grafana
PLUGINS_DIR=/var/lib/grafana/plugins
LOG_DIR=/var/log/grafana
CONF_FILE=$CONF_DIR/grafana.ini
PROVISIONING_CFG_DIR=$CONF_DIR/provisioning
MAX_OPEN_FILES=10000
PID_FILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
DAEMON=$GRAFANA_HOME/bin/grafana
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!I was stuck wondering what i was doing wrong but it seems i needed to use the /etc/init.d/grafana-server to get the configs.Thanks a lot